# Used 1TB hard drive to replace 250GB drive, but can only access 250GB

Tags: windows-7

I have replaced my 250GB with a new 1TB harddisk.

I installed Windows 7, then asked to restore my PC to its former state.

I now have all my old files etc, but the HDD capacity is still showing 250GB like the previous harddisk?

How can I make the harddisk to use the whole space of 1TB, with my data still intact?

Comment: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=167401 - This may be a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have restored a partition. Use Windows 7 Computer namagement tool to expand the partition to 1tb.

[image: First step]

[image: Second step]

Comment: This would work only if your partition is not the "primary" one.